# ServerSocket e Socket

Tags: java, socket, md5

Estou tentando criar um `ServerSocket`:

---

```
public class RunServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        String passwordCript;

        ServerSocket socketRecepcao = new ServerSocket(22300);
        System.out.println("Servidor esperando conexão na porta 22300");

        while (true) {

            Socket socketConexao = socketRecepcao.accept();
            System.out.println("Conexão estabelecida na porta "
                    + socketConexao.getPort());

            InputStream is = socketConexao.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = socketConexao.getOutputStream();

            is.read(buffer);

            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

            BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest());
            passwordCript = hash.toString(16);

            buffer = passwordCript.getBytes();
            os.write(buffer);

            socketConexao.close();
        }

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

**NOTA:** É um código simples para criar `ServerSocket`,

---

Mas recebo essa exceção:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.iamExport.RunServer.main(RunServer.java:20)
```

---

1. Por que essa exceção está sendo lançada?
2. Que cuidados devo tomar depois que o `ServerSocket` funcionar?

**NOTA:** Sei que existem outros tipos de conexão como `API` `HttpClient`, etc., mas estou estudando `socket`...

Comment: Está usando Eclipse? Verifica no Console se não há várias instâncias do programa executando.

Comment: @utluiz, Verifiquei, na verdade está certo. Acabei executando o ServerSocket ele entrou em background... Obrigado pessoal. Estou errado em acreditar que preciso de um método para verificar se uma determinada porta pode ser usada?

Comment: Eduardo, coloque um bloco `try/catch` para tratar as exceções ao retor da chamada ao método `accept()` e, no caso de cair num `catch` com `BindException`, mostra uma mensagem mais específica como "porta em uso".

Comment: @utluiz, vou fazer isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente, já tem algo ouvindo nessa porta (22300). Possivelmente o seu próprio programa, rodando em background -- dê uma olhada nos processos java, certifique-se de matar todos, e tente de novo.